# How to get Azure AAD B2C forgotten password link in selfasserted data uri

Tags: javascript, azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

Due to business requirement we need to use selfasserted:2.0.0 instead of unifiedssp:1.2.0 for login page.
I am unable to find any documentation in azure b2c which I can use to enable forgottenpassword link in the login page built on selfasserted data uri. It is only giving me the option to enable and disable for unifiedssp or unifiedssd.

```
Self Asserted:
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.0.0</DataUri>

Uniffied SSP
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:1.2.0</DataUri>
```

We have tried to add the forgotten password using javascript in the page but simple redirection from the javasript with the error code and description is not working.

Code tried for redirection to relying party end point with the error code:

```
  var element = document.getElementById("forgotPassword");
    element.onclick = function (event) {
        window.location = redirectUri;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you cannot put the built in forgot password link into the selfAsserted page that is not part of a combined sign in/up orchestration step.

Instead, put a link to `https://myapp.com/forgot-password`, then have your app make a new authentication request to the `forgot password` B2C policy.

Comment: okay thanks Jas.  Is it possible to have a cancel button in uniffiedssp data uri page? Couldn't find anything for that as well in the documentation.